# The foreign key component 'RoleId' is not a declared property on type 'ApplicationUserRole'

Tags: entity-framework-6, asp.net-web-api2

1.Here is the model creating function

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("TEST");

        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUserLogin>().Map(c =>
        {
            c.ToTable("UserLogin");
            c.Properties(p => new
            {
                p.UserId,
                p.LoginProvider,
                p.ProviderKey
            });
        }).HasKey(p => new { p.LoginProvider, p.ProviderKey, p.UserId });

         //Mapping for ApiRole
        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationRole>().Map(c =>
        {
            c.ToTable("Role");
            c.Property(p => p.Id).HasColumnName("RoleId");
            c.Properties(p => new
            {
                p.Name
            });
        }).HasKey(p => p.Id);
        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationRole>().HasMany(c => c.Users).WithRequired().HasForeignKey(c => c.RoleId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().Map(c =>
        {
            c.ToTable("User");
            c.Property(p => p.Id).HasColumnName("UserId");
            c.Properties(p => new
            {
                p.AccessFailedCount,
                p.Email,
                p.EmailConfirmed,
                p.PasswordHash,
                p.PhoneNumber,
                p.PhoneNumberConfirmed,
                p.TwoFactorEnabled,
                p.SecurityStamp,
                p.LockoutEnabled,
                p.LockoutEndDateUtc,
                p.UserName
            });
        }).HasKey(c => c.Id);
        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().HasMany(c => c.Logins).WithOptional().HasForeignKey(c => c.UserId);
        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().HasMany(c => c.Claims).WithOptional().HasForeignKey(c => c.UserId);
        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().HasMany(c => c.Roles).WithRequired().HasForeignKey(c => c.UserId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUserRole>().Map(c =>
        {
            c.ToTable("UserRole");
            c.Properties(p => new
            {
                p.UserId,
                p.RoleId
            });
        })
        .HasKey(c => new { c.UserId, c.RoleId });


        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUserClaim>().Map(c =>
        {
            c.ToTable("UserClaim");
            c.Property(p => p.Id).HasColumnName("UserClaimId");
            c.Properties(p => new
            {
                p.UserId,
                p.ClaimValue,
                p.ClaimType
            });
        }).HasKey(c => c.Id);
    }
```

I am getting an error :
"The foreign key component 'RoleId' is not a declared property on type 'ApplicationUserRole'. Verify that it has not been explicitly excluded from the model and that it is a valid primitive property."

The ApplicationUserRole is extending from following class:

```
      //   TKey:
public class IdentityUserRole<TKey>
{
    public IdentityUserRole();

    // Summary:
    //     RoleId for the role
    public virtual TKey RoleId { get; set; }
    //
    // Summary:
    //     UserId for the user that is in the role
    public virtual TKey UserId { get; set; }
}
```

Why does I get this error ?

I have read some of SO threads, that state , the extending properties are identified or mapped with Model binder (code first) and stating that to override those properties in derived classes. Even I have done that, the same error is occured.

And the ApplicationUserRole entity mapping has been done to solve many to many relationship between users and roles entities.

Comment: Did you ever figure this one out?